# Stopping an iteration of an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

I'm iterating an `ArrayList` of clients named **clientList** that contains clients from the class `Client (user,pass)`

```
ArrayList<Client> clientList= new ArrayList<Client>();
```

Here's the iteration. I want to stop the iteration if it founds a given user (user) and if the password (pass) matches:

```java
            for (Client c : clientList) {
                userA = c.getUser();
                if (userA.equals(user)) {
                    passA = c.getPassword();
                    if (passA.equals(pass)) {
                        loginOK = true;
                        found= true;
                    }
```

I was trying the following **while (found == false)** but it's get stucked if it doesnt find an user on the ArrayList:

```java
        while (found == false) { /
            for (Client c : clientList) {
                userA = c.getUser();
                if (userA.equals(user)) {
                    passA = c.getPassword();
                    if (passA.equals(pass)) {
                        loginOK = true;
                        found= true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should also consider using a `HashMap` instead of a `List`.  The key would be the `user` and the value the `pass`.  Then your `for`-loop vanishes; you instead get `if (hashMap.get(user).equals(pass))`.  But you would have to severely change your code for that... the `Client` class would not be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write it this way:

```
while (!found) { 
    for (Cliente c : clientList) {
        userA = c.getUser();
        if (userA.equals(user)) {
            passA = c.getPassword();
            if (passA.equals(pass)) {
                loginOK = true;
                found= true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My guess is that you didn't override equals and hashCode in your `Cliente` class or it's not correct.

Comment: with `break`, `found` is not more needed

Comment: I would not have accepted my answer.  Seeing that the others have the upvotes, I think it's justice to accept one of the others.

Answer (score 8):

You should `break` out of the loop when the value is found.

```
for (something) {
   if (anotherThingIsFound) {
      break;
   }
}
//Execution will continue here when you break...
```

Note, that it also is possible to break out of nested loops, with help of labels. E.g.

```
outer:
while (someCondition) {
   for (criteria) {
      if (somethingHappened) {
         break outer; 
      }
      if (anotherThingHashHappened) {
         break;
      }
   }
   //Execution will continue here if we execute the "normal" break.
}
//Execution will continue here when we execute "break outer;"
```

`continue` does also work with labels.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just `break`?

```
for (Client c : clientList) {
    userA = c.getUser();
    if (userA.equals(user)) {
        passA = c.getPassword();
        if (passA.equals(pass)) {
            loginOK = true;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm assuming you need to tell the difference between getting to the end and *finding* someone and getting to the end and *not* finding someone. You probably only need one variable though, rather than two...)

With your `while` loop attempt, you're going to iterate over the whole list forever if the user isn't found, and even if the user *is* found, it will loop over the whole list once - because your for loop is *inside* the while loop. The while condition is only checked once per iteration *of the while loop*.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `break` keyword:

```java
        for (Client c : clientList) {
            userA = c.getUser();
            if (userA.equals(user)) {
                passA = c.getPassword();
                if (passA.equals(pass)) {
                    loginOK = true;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
```

See [Java break keyword documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use your `found` attribute, introduce a `break` and remove while loop:

```
for (Cliente c : clientList) {
    userA = c.getUser();
    if (userA.equals(user)) {
        passA = c.getPassword();
        if (passA.equals(pass)) {
        loginOK = true;
        found= true;
        }
    }

    if (found)
        break;
}
```

That way, you don't need to use the `while` loop:

Answer (score 1):

Skipped null safety and class cast safety for simplicity

```
public class Cliente {
    public boolean equals(Object other){
         Cliente cOther = (Cliente) other;
         return this.getUser().equals(other.getUser()) &&
                this.getPassword().equals(other.getPassword())
    }
    public int hashCode(){
        return this.getUser().hashCode()*this.getPassword().hashCode();
    }
}

...
Cliente c = new Cliente();
c.setPassword(pass);
c.setUser(user);
boolean found = clientList.contains(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `break` works fine, but if you wanted to do it with a while loop instead then you could do it like this:

```
    Iterator<Client> it = clientList.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext() && !found) {
        Client c = it.next();
        userA = c.getUser();
        if (userA.equals(user)) {
            passA = c.getPassword();
            if (passA.equals(pass)) {
                loginOK = true;
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
```