# Adding a condition which will stop and then continue the loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have an array list containing 4 values inside. I want to stop the loop when found a particular string otherwise the for loop should continue.

I tried using break, but it didn't help.

I tried like below:

```
if(productItem._NAME.equals("FRUITS")) {
                                break;
```

But this will execute only once i.e. if the loop finds "FRUITS" the first time it will stop executing the loop. But I want to continue till I get all the elements from the list but don't want elements "FRUITS"

Comment: You mean `continue;`?

Comment: clearly state your problem. do you want to skip array list items which equals FRUITS?

Comment: iterate through the arraylist and match each value using equals

Comment: Just do nothing in that if loop where it is equal to FRUITS otherwise in else get every other productItem._NAME or simply put not in that if loop and it will run for all other productItems except fruits.

Comment: I tried this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292457/stopping-an-iteration-of-an-arraylist-in-java]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a sample code that you can implement in your code, I am assuming your Arraylist contains object of type String:

```
// Here fruits is the Arraylist<String> object that contains your elements 

    for(String str:fruits)
    {
        if(str.contains("FRUITS"))
        {
         continue;
        }
      System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, for the sake of this example, that your example `productItem` field/variable is of a hypothetical type `Item`:

```
ArrayList<Item> products = new ArrayList<>();
products.addAll(...);

ArrayList<Item> nonFruitProducts = new ArrayList<>();    

for(Item product : products){                //for each product
    if(!product._NAME.equals("FRUITS")){     //with a name that is not FRUITS
        nonFruitProducts.add(product);       //add that product to the results
    }
}
```

Then you can use the resulting `nonFruitProducts` `ArrayList` in the later code which requires a `List` of `Item`s which are not named `"FRUITS"`:

```
for(Item nonFruitProduct: nonFruitProducts){
    doStuffRequiringNoFruits(nonFruitProduct);
}
```